# NCORE bigger than 1 when performing phonon/vibrational calculation(IBRION=5) in VASP?

Tags: vasp, software-assistance, vibrations

When I try to calculate the vibration frequency of TiO2, I set IBRION=5 in VASP, but it turns out I couldn't use NCORE>1 in this situation, once I use NCORE>1, VASP would run for only one ionic step, and then stop.
Is this some kind of bug or there is a more complicated reason?

Here is the error message:

```
 running on   64 total cores
 distrk:  each k-point on   16 cores,    4 groups
 distr:  one band on   16 cores,    1 groups
 vasp.6.3.0 20Jan22 (build Apr 21 2022 08:28:17) gamma-only                     
  
 POSCAR found type information on POSCAR H C O TiCu
 POSCAR found :  5 types and      79 ions                                                                           
 scaLAPACK will be used
 WARNING: type information on POSCAR and POTCAR are incompatible
 POTCAR overwrites the type information in POSCAR
 typ   2 type information:  C  H 
 LDA part: xc-table for Pade appr. of Perdew
 POSCAR found type information on POSCAR H C O TiCu
 POSCAR found :  5 types and      79 ions
 POSCAR, INCAR and KPOINTS ok, starting setup
 FFT: planning ... GRIDC
 FFT: planning ... GRID_SOFT
 FFT: planning ... GRID
 WAVECAR not read
 WARNING: random wavefunctions but no delay for mixing, default for NELMDL
 entering main loop
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
DAV:   1     0.962189968479E+04    0.96219E+04   -0.31354E+05  1592   0.156E+03
DAV:   2     0.120501156595E+04   -0.84169E+04   -0.79375E+04  1648   0.488E+02
DAV:   3    -0.572351588775E+03   -0.17774E+04   -0.17336E+04  1832   0.220E+02
DAV:   4    -0.739169994137E+03   -0.16682E+03   -0.16573E+03  2264   0.724E+01
DAV:   5    -0.761486083389E+03   -0.22316E+02   -0.22300E+02  2984   0.236E+01    0.117E+02
DAV:   6    -0.584545650497E+03    0.17694E+03   -0.37934E+02  2344   0.560E+01    0.549E+01
DAV:   7    -0.557399994994E+03    0.27146E+02   -0.28287E+02  2392   0.362E+01    0.304E+01
DAV:   8    -0.557759287444E+03   -0.35929E+00   -0.66876E+01  2232   0.188E+01    0.246E+01
DAV:   9    -0.556156575211E+03    0.16027E+01   -0.77852E+00  2192   0.798E+00    0.110E+01
DAV:  10    -0.556308157936E+03   -0.15158E+00   -0.35423E+00  2520   0.597E+00    0.479E+00
DAV:  11    -0.556383556331E+03   -0.75398E-01   -0.65556E-01  2304   0.385E+00    0.275E+00
DAV:  12    -0.556459162071E+03   -0.75606E-01   -0.17827E-01  2496   0.156E+00    0.146E+00
DAV:  13    -0.556467749346E+03   -0.85873E-02   -0.82389E-02  2288   0.116E+00    0.625E-01
DAV:  14    -0.556480246505E+03   -0.12497E-01   -0.14617E-02  2288   0.331E-01    0.379E-01
DAV:  15    -0.556481372663E+03   -0.11262E-02   -0.45098E-03  2352   0.197E-01    0.255E-01
DAV:  16    -0.556483184852E+03   -0.18122E-02   -0.29763E-03  2312   0.151E-01    0.163E-01
DAV:  17    -0.556483432934E+03   -0.24808E-03   -0.11567E-03  2600   0.113E-01    0.908E-02
DAV:  18    -0.556483568698E+03   -0.13576E-03   -0.45184E-04  2368   0.612E-02    0.620E-02
DAV:  19    -0.556483608223E+03   -0.39525E-04   -0.10142E-04  2560   0.309E-02    0.524E-02
DAV:  20    -0.556483626361E+03   -0.18139E-04   -0.30529E-05  2432   0.294E-02    0.287E-02
DAV:  21    -0.556483616771E+03    0.95909E-05   -0.27797E-05  2336   0.183E-02    0.151E-02
DAV:  22    -0.556483613639E+03    0.31321E-05   -0.84747E-06  2288   0.829E-03    0.110E-02
DAV:  23    -0.556483612230E+03    0.14088E-05   -0.43880E-06  2328   0.576E-03    0.608E-03
DAV:  24    -0.556483609819E+03    0.24112E-05   -0.10952E-06  2280   0.400E-03    0.348E-03
DAV:  25    -0.556483609611E+03    0.20781E-06   -0.62687E-07  2272   0.185E-03    0.185E-03
DAV:  26    -0.556483609690E+03   -0.78908E-07   -0.69696E-08  1816   0.737E-04    0.159E-03
DAV:  27    -0.556483609605E+03    0.85107E-07   -0.26865E-08  1400   0.463E-04    0.141E-03
DAV:  28    -0.556483609564E+03    0.40040E-07   -0.72716E-09   960   0.259E-04    0.137E-03
DAV:  29    -0.556483609543E+03    0.21508E-07   -0.34761E-09   880   0.201E-04    0.135E-03
DAV:  30    -0.556483609552E+03   -0.86002E-08   -0.18163E-09   880   0.131E-04
   1 F= -.55648361E+03 E0= -.55648209E+03  d E =-.304676E-02  mag=     1.0400
 Finite differences POTIM= 0.01000 DOF= 141
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                             |
|     EEEEEEE  RRRRRR   RRRRRR   OOOOOOO  RRRRRR      ###     ###     ###     |
|     E        R     R  R     R  O     O  R     R     ###     ###     ###     |
|     E        R     R  R     R  O     O  R     R     ###     ###     ###     |
|     EEEEE    RRRRRR   RRRRRR   O     O  RRRRRR       #       #       #      |
|     E        R   R    R   R    O     O  R   R                               |
|     E        R    R   R    R   O     O  R    R      ###     ###     ###     |
|     EEEEEEE  R     R  R     R  OOOOOOO  R     R     ###     ###     ###     |
|                                                                             |
|     VASP internal routines have requested a change of the k-point set.      |
|     Unfortunately, this is only possible if NPAR=number of nodes.           |
|     Please remove the tag NPAR from the INCAR file and restart the          |
|     calculation.                                                            |
|                                                                             |
|       ---->  I REFUSE TO CONTINUE WITH THIS SICK JOB ... BYE!!! <----       |
|                                                                             |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What error is given, I have a suspicion but I don't want to answer randomly

Comment: @TristanMaxson, I just add the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error caused by symmetry breaking as the IBRION=5 routine runs, the simple answer is to simply set ISYM=0 and disable symmetry.  This happens even if you have (1, 1, 1) k-points, counterintuitively when you read what this message seems to be about.